# Angular *ngIf with variable condition in external JSON file

Tags: angular, conditional-statements, angular-ng-if

I am trying to add an `ngIf` condition to a div based on a variable that I get from an external JSON file.

This is what the JSON File looks like:

```
{
    steps: [
        {
            step: 'Step 1',
            condition: "selectedValue === 'village'"
        },
        {
            step: 'Step 2',
            condition: "language === 'english'"
        }
    ]
}
```

So what I am trying to achieve is the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let step of steps">
    <ng-container *ngIf="step.condition">
        {{ step.step }}
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

But I think that because the condition is in string value, the `ngIf` is not processing it correctly.

I have even tried a string interpolation type thing, but alas

`condition: "${language} === 'english'"`

Is there any way to achieve this desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to evaluate javascript code and execute it. Example

HTML

```html
<div *ngFor="let step of steps">
  <ng-container *ngIf="evaluate(step.condition)">
    {{ step.step }}
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

TS

```typescript
evaluate(con: string) {
  return eval(con);
}
```

Comment: “Eval is evil” - just make sure the data you’re eval’ling is 100% under your control.